# Nginx cause CORS error after 1 minute from start uploading a file

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am using NestJs as backend with Nginx, I am getting a CORS error after 1 minute from starting uploading files, I was getting error when I start upload but I solve that after editing nginx config and increase `client_max_body_size` but the error occur after 1 minute since I upload a file, I tried to increase timeout by adding

```
server{
   ...
   proxy_read_timeout 300;
   proxy_connect_timeout 300;
   proxy_send_timeout 300; 
   ...
}
```

but this not solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem was in client side React app in axios that was setting 60s timeout